# Binary tree insert function does not work over 10 entries

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a binary tree with nodes like this:

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node *left = NULL;
    node *right = NULL;
    node();
    node(int data, node* ln = 0, node* rn = 0): info(data), left(ln), right(rn) {}
};

bool addItemToTree(struct node* node, int item, bool isRoot) {
    if (!node)
        return false;

    if (isRoot) {
        node->info = item;
        return true;
    }

    if (!node->left) {
        node->left = new struct node(item);
    }
    else if (!node->right) {
        node->right = new struct node(item);
    }
    else {
        if (node->left->left && node->left->right && (!node->right->left || !node->right->right)) {
            return addItemToTree(node->right, item, false);
        }
        else {
            return addItemToTree(node->left, item, false);
        }   
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    node* root = createRoot();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            addItemToTree(root, i, true);
        }
        else {
            addItemToTree(root, i, false);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, my insert function (adds element to tree) stops working after 10 iterations, meaning it adds elements into an incorrect node (doesn't follow binary tree pattern). Anyone know why it breaks? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not comparing the elements at all, you're just checking existence of the children.

Comment: The posted code does not compile: https://ideone.com/D5VLOB

Comment: Nitpick; prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`.

Comment: @code11 this is true, it's in the format of a tree.

Comment: @Fred Larson small errors you should be able to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's actually after 11 iterations, not 10.

That's because after 11 iterations your tree looks like this:

```
          1
       /     \
     2         3
   /   \     /   \
  4     5   6     7
 / \   / \
8   9 10 11
```

Now you want to add 12 under 6, for that your `addItemToTree`, when looking at 1, needs to go to the right. But it only goes to the right if the right child has no children of its own. In this case the right child of 1 is 3, and it has children of its own, so your method will go to the left, which is wrong.

To fix it, you will need to maintain some auxiliary information about the nodes that would let you decide when to go to the left and when to the right. Some options:

1. Store the total number of nodes in a subtree. If the left subtree has number of children that is 1 less that some power of two, and the right child has less than that, go to the right (try to prove why that works).
2. Store whether a subtree has openings at the current depth. You go to the left child if either `left->hasOpenings` or if `!left->hasOpenings && !right->hasOpenings` (the latter means that the tree is full at the current depth, and needs to be extended). You set `hasOpenings` for a parent of a node whenever you recurse to a left child of the node.
3. In your `addItemToTree` maintain the current depth (the depth of the root being 0). Let `leftmostOne` be the index of the leftmost 1 in the binary representation of `item`. Go to the left if `item & (1 << (leftmostOne - depth - 1)) == 0`. E.g. when you add 9, the `leftmostOne` is 3. Then you will do three iterations, and make the following decisions:

   - At node 1, depth 0, `9 & (1 << (3 - 0 - 1)) = 0`, go left
   - At node 2, depth 1, `9 & (1 << (3 - 1 - 1)) = 0`, go left
   - At node 3, depth 2, `9 & (1 << (3 - 2 - 1)) = 1`, go right

Which is exactly what you want.
Try to prove why this works for the general case.